# Ubuntu installed on wrong disk - how to swap partition to correct disk without uninstalling

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I installed Ubuntu alongside windows and wasn't given an obvious option to install on the SSD disk. Ubuntu then installed on the additional hard disk. Is it possible to swap the partition to the SSD disk without uninstalling Ubuntu?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Lisa

Comment: It might be possible to clone the HDD installed Ubuntu to the SSD; is the SSD blank?

Comment: It is a new computer so the SSD just has windows on it

Comment: Is your intention to have a dual boot system [win 10 and ubuntu] on the same SDD and use the HDD for common data stor? Perhaps you can edit your question to supply some particulars. BTW I don't think swapping partitions across different physical devices is possible.

Comment: yes, I intend to have a dual boot system with windows and ubuntu on the same SSD. The HDD is to be used just for storage to be accessed by both systems. Does cloning the HDD require a boot device? Perhaps it would be easier to uninstall ubuntu and reinstall on the SDD?

Comment: If you clone partition, then you may have duplicate UUIDs, And then have to change UUID and edit all the system files to change UUID (mostly grub & fstab). While that can be done, just easier to reinstall. I do like to have another small install on my data drive as a backup way to boot.

Comment: @LMarfell, It's probably better, easier, and faster for you to install Ubuntu a second time - please select "something else" for the install method. If you intend to stor files and have those file accessible by either OS it's probably easier to reformat the HDD as NTFS. You shouldn't concern yourself with uninstalling Ubuntu. After you've installed on the SDD and reformatted HDD remember to execute sudo update-grub.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling ubuntu and managed to partition it onto the SSD. :). Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible! But If its better to reinstall Ubuntu.

**Using Clonezilla**:

- Download the latest Clonezilla ISO : [64bit iso from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_stable/2.4.7-8/clonezilla-live-2.4.7-8-amd64.iso/download)
- Either create a bootable USB or add Clonezilla Grub Entry to your GRUB
- Boot into it.
- Select Clone parts.
- Then Clone the partition on which you have insalled Ubuntu and keep the image.
- Now Make appropriate partition on your SSD.
- Boot into Clonezilla
- Now select "Restore Parts" and then Restore it onto your new partition.
- Now boot into a **Ubuntu Live USB**
- Reinstall **GRUB**

that is,

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdxz /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdx
update-grub  
exit
```

**NOTE : Above, I have mentioned "sdxy" as your new / partition, sdxz as your EFI partition . Please make appropriate changes. (it should be sth like sda1 or sdb2 ...)**

- Correct the UUID entries in the fstab file.

Open another terminal and execute :

```
sudo blkid
```

Open another terminal and execute :

```
sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Replace the UUID entries of old partitions with new ones.
with those of the output given from the blkid command.

Now reboot.

But again, If you have just installed Ubuntu and installed no packages on it, It is preferable to do a **clean** installation on your required partition.